# Queue in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, queue

I want to add a role in the queue when the button is pressed by another user, until the liveTimer() finishes and then starts executing for the other user

For example: when a user presses the button, liveTimer() starts working, and if another user presses the button while liveTimer() is still running for the first user, the second user is put in the queue, and after liveTimer() finishes working for the first user, it moves to work for the second user automatically until the queue becomes empty

What is the best way to do this in Kotlin for Android?

```
cameraBt.setOnClickListener() {
        liveTimer()
    }
```

this is what liveTimer() do

```
fun liveTimer() {
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    val cameraIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    cameraIntent.data = Uri.parse("https://shielded-fortress-04099.herokuapp.com/")
    startActivity(cameraIntent)

    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(30 * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(timeLeft: Long) {

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            startActivity(intent)
            Toast.makeText(
                this@HomeActivity,
                "the allowed time has finished",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }

    }.start()
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No there is no error  but i want to add queue to To organize the role of users when the button is pressed and run the liveTimer method and I dnk how to write it correctly  @AlexMamo